Change the context.area.type in Headless mode
I've want to run a script Headless and need to set the bpy.context.area.type but it's confusing. Some sources suggest that setting bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR' and using bpy.ops.graph is feasible, while others indicate it's a GUI-only feature.
For instance, one thread on Blender Stack Exchange mentions that such operations cannot be done in headless mode due to the lack of a UI context. Conversely, another thread seems to imply it is possible.
Given this, is it actually feasible to use bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR' and bpy.ops.graph in a headless Blender environment, or are these functionalities strictly limited to GUI interactions?
I searched for an answer but did not get one that works. Hopfully this will be clear after this post if it actually does work.

Yes it does only took ages to find here's how
get the conext you need
def get_context(type):
    for screen in bpy.data.screens:
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == type:
                context_override = {"area": area, "screen": screen}
                return context_override

after that temporarly override the context to match the needed one
override = get_context("GRAPH_EDITOR")
with context.temp_override(**override):
     # bpy.ops.graph is now usable
     # your code

